# QGIS-I have 37 polygons, can I bulk create 2 other sets of 37 that are 1 px larger all the way round and 1px smaller

Tags: qgis, polygon, error

I have 37 polygons covering a Lakes spatial extent at a particular point in time. I need to bulk create 2 sets of polygons. One 1 px larger all the way around and one 1px smaller to calculate the area so I can work out the error for the initial polygons created.

Other suggestions about working out the error are welcome!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but working with geographic features, the unit used is definitely not pixels, assuming px means pixels. Pixels are for graphic software and QGIS works with planar units such as meters, feet or geographic like degrees. Anyway, the way to "shrink" or "expand" a polygon feature is by using the buffer function.

Comment: So I have had to hand draw the shapes due to the nature of the imagery, however I need to create error bars to account for human error in drawing the boundaries. The unit (1px = 30m) is less the question - more is there a bulk way to do it? Or do I need to do it one by one?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my previous comment, you need the buffer function (under the vector menu). I'm away from my pc so can't provide screenshots.

Comment: @Techie_Gus Thanks - pointed me in the right direction and while the problem is somewhat solved - I keep getting error messages in the batch log. Not sure what this means - not brilliantly tech person so I guess 1 by 1 is the answer for now!


"arguments did not match any overloaded call: QgsGeometry(): too many arguments QgsGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType' See log for more details"

Comment: can you provide more info as to how you're batching?